# paint in qcustomplot by signal from Arduino

Tags: c++, qt, arduino

I would like to do a project that output value from Arduino and paint shapes in Qt. I am not sure if `QCustomPlot` can do this. Would you please give me some suggestion?

For example, I create a Qt GUI for entering the position(x,y) to Arduino and do calculation, then Arduino send the value signal to Qt and paint the shape on the position I want. Is it possible?

Comment: Sure this is possible. Start here https://github.com/dmontanari/qplotduino, this is a project doing all that

Answer (score 0):

A few years ago, i do something like that using [QWT](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) and [QextSerialPort](https://github.com/qextserialport/qextserialport). You have to connect your Arduino using a serial por (in Windows COM1, COM2...), and you will be able to read/write data from the buffer.

Now, Qt, integrates a native support for this task, check [QtSerialPort Support](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtserialport-index.html), to configure your port check this class [QSerialPort](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qserialport.html). How to read the data? Use QByteArray, an example:

```
 QByteArray responseData = serial->readAll();
 while(serial->waitForReadyRead(100))
       responseData += serial->readAll();
```

Now store all the bytes in a [QVector](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html) of type double.

```
QVector<double> data;
QDataStream stream(line);
stream >> data;
```

This data will be ploted by [QCustomPlot](http://qcustomplot.com/). Example:

```
int numSamples = data.size();
QVector<double> x(numSamples), y(numSamples); // initialize with entries 0..100
for (int i=0; i<numSamples; ++i)
{
  x[i] = i/50.0 - 1; // x goes from -1 to 1
  y[i] = data[i]; // In this line copy the data from your Arduino Buffer and apply what you want, maybe some signal processing
}
// create graph and assign data to it:
customPlot->addGraph();
customPlot->graph(0)->setData(x, y);
// give the axes some labels:
customPlot->xAxis->setLabel("x");
customPlot->yAxis->setLabel("y");
// set axes ranges, so we see all data:
customPlot->xAxis->setRange(-1, 1);
customPlot->yAxis->setRange(0, 1);
customPlot->replot();
```

Enjoy!